# Chart.js customize tooltips

Tags: chart.js, tooltip

Try to figure how to store customized info text for the tooltip of each bar. (see image below)?

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I0s9.jpg)

The percentage comes from the calculation of the list price bar and sale price bar, and the text will change based on the positive and negative percentage.

Here is the code. 
The tooltip text is currently hardcoded.

```js
  Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 10;

var listPriceData = {
  label: 'Average list price',
  data: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600],
  backgroundColor: '#ff937f',
  borderWidth: 0,
  yAxisID: "y-axis-0"
};

var salePriceData = {
  label: 'Average sale price',
  data: [150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650],
  backgroundColor: '#fed6ce',
  borderWidth: 0,
  yAxisID: "y-axis-0"
};

var allData = {
  labels: ["8/2019", "9/2019", "10/2019", "11/2019", "12/2019", "1/2020"],
  datasets: [listPriceData, salePriceData]
};

var chartOptions = {
  legend: {
    display: false
  },
  hover: {
    animationDuration: 0
  },
  animation: {
    duration: 1,
    onComplete: function (el) {
      var chartInstance = this.chart,
          ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
      ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(
                  Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 12,
                  Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle = "bold",
                  Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily
                );
      ctx.fillStyle = el.chart.config.options.defaultFontColor;
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

      this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
        var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
        meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
          var data = dataset.data[index];
          ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
        });
      });
    }
  },
  tooltips: {
      enabled: false,
      custom: function(tooltipModel) {
          // Tooltip Element
          var tooltipEl = document.getElementById('home-appreciation-tooltip');

          // Create element on first render
          if (!tooltipEl) {
              tooltipEl = document.createElement('div');
              tooltipEl.id = 'home-appreciation-tooltip';
              tooltipEl.innerHTML = '<table></table>';
              document.body.appendChild(tooltipEl);
          }

          // Hide if no tooltip
          if (tooltipModel.opacity === 0) {
              tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
              return;
          }

          // Set caret Position
          tooltipEl.classList.remove('above', 'below', 'no-transform');
          if (tooltipModel.yAlign) {
              tooltipEl.classList.add(tooltipModel.yAlign);
          } else {
              tooltipEl.classList.add('no-transform');
          }

          function getBody(bodyItem) {
              return bodyItem.lines;
          }

          // Set Text
          if (tooltipModel.body) {
              var titleLines = tooltipModel.title || [];
              var bodyLines = tooltipModel.body.map(getBody);

              var innerHtml = '<thead>';

              titleLines.forEach(function(title) {
                  innerHtml += '<tr><th>' + "<h5>+0.2%</h5>" + '</th></tr>';
              });
              innerHtml += '</thead><tbody>';

              bodyLines.forEach(function(body, i) {
                  var colors = tooltipModel.labelColors[i];
                  // innerHtml += '<tr><td>' + body + '</td></tr>';
                  innerHtml += '<tr><td>' + "Homes are selling for 110% of list price" + '</td></tr>';
              });
              innerHtml += '</tbody>';

              var tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table');
              tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml;
          }

          // `this` will be the overall tooltip
          var position = this._chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

          // Display, position, and set styles for font
          tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
          tooltipEl.style.position = 'absolute';
          tooltipEl.style.left = position.left + window.pageXOffset + tooltipModel.caretX - 65 + 'px';
          tooltipEl.style.top = position.top + window.pageYOffset + tooltipModel.caretY - 85 + 'px';
          tooltipEl.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
      }
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      barPercentage: 1,
      categoryPercentage: 0.6,
      ticks: {
        fontColor: "#8292A2",
        fontSize: 10,
      },
      gridLines: {
        display: false,
        color: "rgb(226, 230, 233)",
        offsetGridLines: true
      }
    }],

    yAxes: [
      {
        display: false,
      },
      {
        type: "linear",
        id: "y-axis-0",
        display: true,
        ticks: {
          fontColor: "#202C4A",
          fontSize: 10,
          fontStyle: "bold",
          beginAtZero: true,
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            return "$" + value + "k";
          }
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: true,
          borderDash: [4, 2],
          color: "rgb(226, 230, 233)"
        }
      }]
  }
};

Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#263151';

var myCanvas = document.getElementById("homeAppreciationChartCanvas").getContext('2d');

var barChart = new Chart(myCanvas, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: allData,
  options: chartOptions
});
```

```css
canvas {
  margin-top: 100px;
  max-width: 700px;
}



#home-appreciation-tooltip {
  background-color: #1d2c49;
  border-radius: 3px;
  max-width: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  padding: 5px;
}


#home-appreciation-tooltip:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: 100%;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #1d2c49;
}



#home-appreciation-tooltip table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#home-appreciation-tooltip h5 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 3px 0;
  line-height: 1em;
}

#home-appreciation-tooltip p,
#home-appreciation-tooltip td {
  color: #ed6c54;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1em;
}

#home-appreciation-tooltip td,
#home-appreciation-tooltip th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

#home-appreciation-tooltip td {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#home-appreciation-tooltip th {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>

    <canvas id="homeAppreciationChartCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: So each tooltip should show the percentage with the static text, is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Yes. the percentage comes from the calculation of the list price bar and sale price bar, and the text will change based on the positive and negative percentage.